# Is there a way to include Behind / Ahead info in oh-my-zsh Prompt?

Tags: command-line, git, zsh, prompt

I know using the below command, we can get the results of commits that is Behind and Ahead.

```
git rev-list --left-right --count origin/master...`git branch --show-current`
```

But I would like to know, if this info can be somehow added into the `oh-my-zsh` prompt ?

Comment: Do you mean the Oh-my-Zsh *prompt*?

Comment: Yes, you are right.